# ImportError Tkinter

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, importerror, anaconda

I'm running Python 2.7.5 on OSX 10.8.4
I installed Python 2.7.5 with Anaconda.
When I try

```
import _Tkinter
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _Tkinter
```

I tried to look on different forums including stackoverflow in the first place, and I found this error like 1000 times, but didn't manage to find a solution or to figure out what I had to do. I DO already have X11 (don't know if this helps but I saw somewhere it could be needed).
Thank's!

Comment: Does `import Tkinter` work?

Comment: yeah whats the `_` for?

Comment: I get this : 

    Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "/opt/local/Library
    /Frameworks/Python.framewo/Versions /2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk ImportError: No module 
    named _tkinter

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import Tkinter
```

Don't use an underscore!